# split a horizontal line into serveral lines in a table

Tags: tables, rules

I know `\cline{i-j}` to span a line from column i to j. But if in one line, I want a line only spanning from {1-1} and then {3-3} for example, how can I make it?

| a | b | c |

--  --

|d | e | f |

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use `\cline{i-i}` to span only column `i`.

The `booktabs` package also provides `\cmidrule` that can be with `l` or `r` to shorten the line in the left or right end, respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
\cline{1-1}
\cline{3-3}
d & e & f
\end{tabular}

% with booktabs
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
a & b & c \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
d & e & f \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```